# encrypting/decrypting password stored in config file

Tags: bash, encryption

I have a simple Bash script automating tasks which require password-based authentication.
Currently I store the credentials in plain text:

```
$ cat ~/.myconfig
username=foo
password=bar
```

Obviously that's bad - so I wonder whether there's a simple way to encrypt/decrypt the password using my public/private key pair. Using Yet Another Password for the encryption wouldn't gain much, so I want it to happen pretty much automatically.

I've done some research (around here and elsewhere), but am way out of my depth on this one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store password into md5 sum, add some salt before.

## create:

```
\#!/bin/bash

salt=12345_

protocol=sha1sum

read -p "Enter login: " username
read -p -s "Password: " pass1
read -p -s "Repeat: pass2

if [ "pass1 != pass2" ]; then echo "Pass missmatch"; exit 1; else password=pass1; fi

echo -en "$username " >> ./mypasswd
echo -e "${salt}${password} | $protocol | awk '{print $1}'" >> ./mypqsswd
```

## read:

```
\#!/bin/bash
salt=12345_ #(samesalt)
protocol=sha1sum

read -p "Enter username: " username
read -p -s "Enter password: " password

if [ `grep $username ./mypasswd | awk '{print $2}' != `echo -e "`echo ${salt}${password} | $protocol | awk '{print $2}'`" ]; then echo -e "wrong username or password"; exit 127; else echo -e "login successfull"; fi
```

There's your code.

Comment: MD5 is insecure.  Use SHA instead. (`sha1sum`, `sha256sum`, `sha512sum`, _etc_., depending on the hash length you'd like.)

Comment: it's better then save in plain text, and i just show how it works..
 i just add protocol variable, so just change it, and you get sha256 sha512.. etc

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? The OP stated they need a method of encrypting and DECRYPTING a password. AFAIK, SHA is secure _because_ it's infeasible to decrypt.

Answer (score 4):

To automate your task means providing the password; it won't make a difference is you encrypt/obfuscate the password, you'll need to provide the decrypting too.
The only way around this dilemma is an agent-like program, as for example [ssh-agent](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/ssh-agent), which stores your passwords for you.

(edit: corrected link)

Comment: ssh-agent sounds like what I'm looking for - however, I can't quite figure out how exactly I should employ it. a) Assuming I load the encrypted password from the file, how do I then decrypt it? b) What do I use to encrypt the password in the first place? (I expect this to be a separate, manual step.)

Comment: ssh-agent was given as an example for how it could be implemented. However, this is a specific solution for ssh-related connections. For your specific situation something similar could be created, but the how depends on your application.

Comment: I guess I was thinking of a keyring/keychain manager to determine and access the respective keypair - but there might not be a portable solution for that. (My application is just a Bash script dispatching some commands - think HTTP basic auth with curl.)

Comment: What is the solution for your automated process? i struck into same situation.

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to hide the password then store its SHA1 hash. The compare the hash of the entered password with your stored hash.

Comment: And change file permissions `chmod go-rw myconfig` against dictionary attacks.

Comment: 'Automated' means there is no entered password. There's nobody to enter it.

Comment: GregS is right - if I automate entering the actual password by requiring the user to enter another password, there's not much point in storing the actual password in the first place.